# Adding two length m vectors results in a matrix with dimensions m * m

Tags: numpy, matrix, tensorflow, vector, linear-algebra

In numpy, when I have a vector with size `(m,)` and another vector with size `(m, 1)`, adding the two gives a matrix with size `(m, m)`. However, I just want the vector result. How do I go about doing this?

Edit: I am in fact using tensorflow and the `(m, 1)` vector is actually `(m, ?)`. However, when I am adding biases to the dot product between the weights `(n, m) . (m, ?)` I get a `(m, m)` matrix which essentially replicates the bias across the rows. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broadcasting goes

```
(m,)+(m,1)
(1,m]+(m,1)    # match number of dimensions
(m,m)          # match shapes
```

To avoid this reshape one array to (m,1), or reshape the other to (m,).

Answer (score 0):

Reshape the numpy array with size (m,)

```
array=np.reshape(array,(m,1))
```